# В чем разница между string и string&?

Tags: c++, строки, функции

В чем разница между:

```
void function(string stroka) {
}
```

и

```
void function(string& stroka) {
}
```

Гуглил, не нашёл инфы. Там все, что угодно, но не мой вопрос, даже близко. Если подобный вопрос был на [ru]SO, дайте ссылку...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В первом случае создается **копия** строки и передается в функцию. Все, что вы будете делать с ней, никак не скажется на оригинале.

Во втором случае передается **ссылка** на существующую строку. Все, что вы будете делать с ней, вы будете делать с оригиналом.

И, кстати, поэтому

```
function("Hello");
```

в первом случае сработает, а во втором — нет.

О `const string&` поговорим в другой раз :)

Answer (score 1):

Дополню ответ Harry.

Знак амперсанда в приведенном ниже примере означает не "оператор взятия адреса", а "ссылка на объект".

```
string str = "Hello World!";
string& stroka = str; // ссылка на объект str
```

Если сказать еще проще, ссылка — это псевдоним объекта на который ссылается ссылка.

```
void function1(string stroka)
{
    stroka = "Something..."; // Это параметр (копия основного объекта str)
    cout << &stroka << endl; // Имеет другой адрес, не такой как у str
}

void function2(string& stroka)
{
    stroka = "Something..."; // Тут stroka играет роль псевдонима str
    cout << &stroka << endl; // Имеет тот же адрес, что и str
}



int main()
{
    string str = "Hello World!";
    
    cout << "address str: " << &str << endl; // Адрес переменной str
    cout << "value std: " << str << endl; // Значение переменной str

    cout << endl;

    cout << "Function 1." << endl;
    function1(str);
    cout << str << endl; // Значение str не изменилось!

    cout << endl;

    cout << "Function 1." << endl;
    function2(str);
    cout << str << endl; // Значение str изменилось, в результате работы function2


    return 0;
}
```

Что касается ссылок на константные значения, то принцип работы у них точно такой же, как и у ссылок на неконстантные, за исключением того, что изменить значение объекта, на которую ссылается ссылка, будет ***невозможно***

```
void function3(const string& stroka)
{
    stroka = "Something..."; // Будет ошибка!

    cout << stroka << endl; // Все ок, тк мы не пытаемся изменить данные

    cout << &stroka << endl; // Имеет тот же адрес, что и str
}
```

Comment: один момент - нет "константных ссылок". ссылки и так не изменяемы (то есть, они константы "автоматически"). А то, что Вы называете "константной ссылкой" - это "ссылка на константу". да, все привыкли так говорить, но для ответа это все таки нужно правильно.

Comment: @KoVadim учту на будущее)

Comment: Просто подумайте о том, что если бы существовал "константная ссылка", то ссылку нельзя было бы менять (а и обычную ссылку нельзя тоже), а вот сам объект, куда оно указывает - можно было бы (но это не так)